# Strategy for avoiding threadpool starvation while performing cpu bound jobs in a queued fashion

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, thread-safety

My aim is to avoid using threadpool threads for CPU bound work, thus avoiding a situation where IIS stops responding to new requests.

**Can you see any problems with the code below?** Is this a safe/clean approach? Can you offer any improvements?

```
    private static ConcurrentQueue<Job> Jobs = new ConcurrentQueue<Job>();
    static int threadCount = 0;

    private void QueueJob(Job job)
    {

        lock(Jobs)
        {
            Jobs.Enqueue(job);
            if (threadCount == 0)
            {

                Interlocked.Increment(ref threadCount); 
                var t= new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConsumeQueue));              
                t.Start();

            }
        }



    }
    private void ConsumeQueue()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (Jobs)
            { 
                if (!Jobs.Any())
                {
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadCount);
                    return;
                }
            }

            Job j;

            var jobToDo = Jobs.TryDequeue(out j);

            if (jobToDo)
            {
                DoCPUBoundWork(j);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Concerned that `ConsumeQueue` spins without restraint when the queue is empty. Thinking about a better solution.

Comment: Looks like a threadpool to me... (though not a very good one 'cos the spinning, as commented by @spender

Comment: Code edited slightly.. Are you still saying that this will spin?

Comment: Can you look at it again now? I like your solution but would like to get my head round this bit of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic Queue that should satisfy your needs:

```
//sealed so we don't have to implement full IDisposable pattern
sealed class Q:IDisposable
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private BlockingCollection<Action> queue =
        new BlockingCollection<Action>(new ConcurrentQueue<Action>());

    public Q()
    {
        new Thread(() => RunQueue()).Start();
    }

    private void RunQueue()
    {
        while(!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Action action;
            try
            {
                //lovely... blocks until something is available
                //so we don't need to deal with messy synchronization
                action = queue.Take(cts.Token); 
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException)
            {
                break;
            }
            action();
        }
    }

    public void AddJob(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            queue.Add(action,cts.Token);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("Q is disposed",e);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

To be used as follows:

```
Q actionQueue=new Q();
actionQueue.AddJob(() => Console.WriteLine("action1"));
actionQueue.AddJob(() => Console.WriteLine("action2"));
actionQueue.AddJob(() => Console.WriteLine("action3"));
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution. I was wondering if there is any downside to blocking here. It seems not.

Comment: Thanks @Tom ;) I don't think that blocking here is any kind of problem. I think it would be more costly to let the thread terminate and to fire up a new one. I suppose the ThreadPool probably parks threads in a similar fashion when there's no work to be done.

Comment: After considering in depth all of the answers both on here and on CodeReview, and trying a few things out, in the end I went with spender's awesome `Q` because it answers the question perfectly, and offers an improvement over my strategy.

Comment: @Tom: funnily enough, I've just found a good use for this too. Exception handling could do with improvement though!

Answer (score 1):

There is posibility that your thread terminates before Enqueue job

```
lock (Jobs)
{ 
     if (!ResizeJobs.Any())
     {
         Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadCount);
         return;
     }
}
```

And after this another job will execute
    Jobs.Enqueue(job);

I think you don't need to terminate worker thread. It should wait for work in sleep state

Comment: Looks fine (minor: try to use compareexchange in QueueJob). But I still don't understand - why you need terminate worker thread.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, there's no reason to start and stop like this. I have gone with the awesome `Q` from spender.